# "I keep mistaking asses for humans"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Oxford dictionary does not seem to have an entry for the verb mistake.

**P.S.**
Oxford dictionary does have it. Sorry, I missed it. :(

However, Wiktionary has one and it says

> To understand wrongly, taking one thing for another, or someone for someone else.

An example of this usage in Wikipedia goes

> Sorry, I mistook you for my brother. You look very similar.

1. Is using mistake as a verb correct ?
2. Can I use it in the continuous form ? e.g.

   > I keep mistaking asses for humans.

Comment: 1. Yes.  2. Yes.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mistake (scroll to the second fat black line).  Wrong Oxford?

Comment: @Victor Bazarov, oops, I must admit. I somehow missed that. Oxford dictionary does have this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A meaning of *take* can be "to believe" or equivalent to "have the impression of being", especially when talking about the characteristics of a person or something about a person.

> I take him to be a hardworking person.
>
> I took his theories as truth, but in the end they were lies.

Similarly, *mis*take (the prefix *mis-* meaning *wrongly* or *erroneously*) can mean an erroneous "*take*", in the above sense.

> I mistook him for a hardworking person.  He's actually lazy.
>
> I mistook his theories as truth, and it turns out in the end they were lies.

*Mistake* can be used in any tense and the *-take* part has the same forms as plain *take*: *mistake*, *mistaking*, *mistook*, *mistaken*.
.